# pandas matches rows using startswith but not equals, for stripped string?

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas dataframe containing strings from an Excel file, loaded using `pd.read_excel`.

There are multiple rows where the cells look like this in Excel:

[image]

There are trailing tabs in the Excel cells, so I have stripped the strings:

```
df.DIST_NAME = df.DIST_NAME.str.strip()
```

Subsequently the following query produces results:

```
df[df.DIST_NAME.str.startswith("CITY OF WESTMINSTER")]
```

But the following query produces no results:

```
df[df.DIST_NAME == "CITY OF WESTMINSTER"]
```

I'm stumped. How can this be happening? How can I debug?

If it's helpful I could upload a sample of the Excel file to a filebin.

Comment: can you try `df.loc[df.DIST_NAME.str.startswith("CITY OF WESTMINSTER"), "DIST_NAME"].unique()` this might help you if there is still something at the end of your string that `strip` did not remove?